# Tricky styling creating blank space

Tags: html, css

`Hello there`, I just created this datepicker thingy which turned out pretty cool except that it creates some really annoying and weird looking white space below the divs when empty and appears higher, see the fiddle > http://jsfiddle.net/VtKkM/2/ Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: On a side note, it looks like you may have an off-by-one error when populating the default value with your `data-preset`... ;-)  Specifically with the day.  Nifty little date picker though.

Comment: Yeah I figured that, be sure you're viewing /2/ - the last edit from me :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haven't figured out the problem as of yet, but it seems that it doesn't like it when the spans are empty.  One workaround, at least for now, is to replace your blank options with just a space (`&nbsp;`) so that there's still the illusion that it's empty but the spans still technically contain a value.  This may not be a permanent solution, but it'll work for now.

To elaborate:

Line 2 of your js would go from
`var days = '<option></option>',`
 to 
`var days = '<option>&nbsp;</option>',`

and line 32 would go from `}).parent().prepend('<span></span>');` to `}).parent().prepend('<span>&nbsp;</span>');`

Comment: I hear ya... still trying to find a better explanation for you.  I've run into this in the past, but can't for the life of me remember the logic behind it.

Comment: @php_nub_qq I really quite liked Mehdi's css solution, but be cautious because it's CSS3 and support is still relatively thin.  Updated my answer if you needed specific code (not likely) to add the spaces.  Good luck!

Comment: It is definitely better than white spaces from coding point of view but yet when you inspect it it's not fitting well, this smells like a trouble maker for me, I'd rather stick with white spaces

Comment: When employing my method on your jsFiddle I'm not seeing any issues with it, nor can I think of any real downside to it other than it maybe being a bit of a hack (though I guess it's not a hack if nothing else works...)

Answer (score 1):

Its for line height and your font size of page you can fix it by

Add line height style to your **datePicker** class like this:

```
line-height: 8px;
```

or change font-size like:

```
font-size: 10px;
```

**Edit:**

and for moving when you pick a some value from select you should set your span to **position: absolute;**

```
.datePicker > div > span{
   position: absolute;
}
```

**Edit2:**

or you can set space value in first time in your span, change `<span></span>` to `<span>&nbsp;</span>`

**Edit3:**
i changed this lines to add **space** in initial between span tag, check   values that add onload datepicker:

```
$.each(picker.children(), function () {
    $(this).wrap('<div>').change(function () {
        if ($(this).hasClass('month')) {
            $(this).prev().html(months[$(this).val() - 1]);
        } else {
            $(this).prev().html($(this).val());
        }
    }).parent().prepend('<span>&nbsp;</span>');

    if ($(this).hasClass('month')) {
        $(this).prev().html(months[$(this).val()]?months[$(this).val()]:"&nbsp;");
    } else {
        $(this).prev().html($(this).val()?$(this).val():"&nbsp;");
    }
});
```

**Edit 4:**

and css way, you can fixed it by add padding style to empty span like this:

```
.datePicker > div > span:empty{
    padding:5px;
}
```

Comment: neither one of these works correctly, you can try it yourself on the fiddle to see what happens

Comment: @php_nub_qq i fixed it for picking value from list, try with position absolute for span

Comment: I can't get it to work this way.. Although what I've done is I've given the spans a display: inline-block and then give them min width and height and I've gotten one step closer to the solution

Comment: Yup white spaces work, but it's not an elegant solution. I am sticking to this for now and hoping for a css god to appear. +rep bro

Comment: The Edit 4 css solution is a good one, EXCEPT that `:empty` is CSS3, so you lose a lot of support for it very quickly.  Great solution for down the road though.

Comment: @php_nub_qq please check Edit4.. you need only add padding css to empty span... like my sample.

Comment: @Mike yes its true, The :empty selector is supported in all major browsers, except IE8 and earlier.

Comment: @php_nub_qq browser support for empty selector: http://www.browsersupport.net/CSS/%3Aempty

Answer (score 0):

```
.datePicker > div {
display:inline;
position:relative;
min-width: 18px;
min-height:28px;  
padding:0 5px 0 5px;
}
```

Just change display:inline-block to display:inline

Comment: That may address the white space issue but it creates a bunch more issues for him...

Comment: This does exactly what I want it to do, but then the boxes get so tiny and inline elements cannot have their width and height set QQ :(

Answer (score 0):

The part about it appearing high I could fix with giving .datePicker select a 5px margin.

Comment: That doesn't really fix it :/

Comment: @php_nub_qq doesn't it fix the div appearing high? you can just put your finger over the white space when you look at it? j.k. I looked at the source code and your white space is being created because of an additional option that has no text or value. not sure what to do about it though.

Comment: It is supposed to be there, it stands for none, empty date